# Cleat tension is too high

Tags: spd, cleat

I've been using SPD pedal (PD-EH500) with SH56 cleat

I just got a new pedals (XTR 9100) and adjusted the tension to the lowest setting.

I find it very hard to remove the shoes from the new pedal even though I set the tension at the lowest.

Is it possible for an SPD pedal have a defect in adjusting the tension?
Or maybe the XTR pedals are too high end, and it's doesn't match well with SH56 cleat?

Or something else?

What should I look for to fix this?

Comment: Are the new pedals on the bike already, or are you testing before fitting them? What are your soles like? Could they be catching on the pedal?

Comment: It’s likely to be your shoes as Chris mentioned. My XTR pedals, set at minimum tension, are absurdly loose. The tension is virtually nonexistent. This is because the soles of my shoes float ~2mm above the pedal and don’t interfere with the clip mechanism.

Comment: Are your cleats new, too? Can you try with some mate's shoes?

Comment: I'm using the same shoe and cleat I've been using, and I have no problem with my old bike (with old pedal).. 

The shoe is Shimano CT5. 
I don't understand what you mean by `Could they be catching on the pedal?`

I've installed the pedal on a new bike.

Comment: It could be that the rubber sole of the shoe is hitting the pedal somewhere and you are working against the rubber/friction and not the spring mechanism. But I find that unlikely. Maybe you’ve turned the tension screw in the wrong direction?